# How to make pages that arent indexed for ajax applications

Tags: ajax, page-template

I'm using a content section on my homepage to switch through multiple loops with ajax tabs and to do that a tutorial told me to make multiple pages and assign each page with a different template which contains the loop I want to display. But by doing that I'm creating top level pages that display loops on a blank page without styling. That makes me think they will get indexed and I'll have the unstyled pages showing up in searches. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Could you please add a link to this tutorial? Thanks. (Hard to imagine without seeing actual code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the constant DOING_AJAX to check if a current request is AJAX or not.  This would let you do something like this in your templates:

```
if ( DOING_AJAX ) {
    //show your content
} else {
    //return 404 error
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
}
```

Comment: This is didn't seem to work. I put the loop where //show your content is but it still shows when I go to the page.